# Odoo access ir.config_paramter in report

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-15

I want to access and print a config parameter in a report.

I have tried this

```
<div t-if="ir.config_paramter"> 
    <span t-field="ir.config_paramter.mymodule.myhtmlfield"/>
</div>
```

But I get an error saying it does not know 'ir'

The report I am trying to edit is `account.report_invoice_document`

What do I need to do to correctly print the field on the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value of your `ir_config_parameter` via `data` argument in `get_report` function, or include it via a computed field in your report related method.

For example:

```
ir_parameter_value = fields.Char(compute="_compute_ir_parameter_value")

  def _compute_ir_parameter_value(self):
    for record in self:
      record.ir_parameter_value = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_parameter("parameter_key")
```

Answer (score 0):

**config_paramter**

is it a typo?
have do you include dependencies in **manifest**.py?